# How to query Amazon DynamoDB from different regions and credentials

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I need to delete multiple items exist in multiple tables (name with different environment eg. table-env1, table-env2) in multiple regions with different access key(credentials)

I'm using dynogels to config my AWS region and credentials. However, no matter I use forEach, for loop or map, it will not update the config, or use the last arguments. Or I have to hard code as params[0], params[1], etc. for each promise chain?

```js
       

       for (var i = 0; i < environments.length; i++) {
            var dynogels = require('dynogels-promisified');
            if (params[i]) {
                if (params[i][0]) {
                    dynogels.AWS.config.update({
                        region: params[i][0]
                    })
                }
                if (params[i][1]) {
                    dynogels.AWS.config.update({
                        credentials: new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials({
                            profile: params[i][1]
                        })
                    })
                }
                if(params[i][2]){
                    console.log(params[i][0]);
                    var table = dynogels.define('Account', {
                        hashKey: 'hashKey',
                        rangeKey: 'rangeKey',
                        tableName: `table-${params[i][2]}`
                    });
                    console.log(params[i][2])
                    removeUser(params[i][2], table);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: IAM credentials are global and can be used in all regions (except special regions like GovCloud and China). Do you definitely need to use a different set of credentials for each region/table (because of special regions or because of IAM permissions scoped to a single region/table)?

Comment: This is our company policy, I can't actually change it, now they have different credentials for different regions/tables. Mainly is for security reason, not all people can access all environments as we have multiple teams to look after different tables.

Comment: OK, makes sense. There is a feature request related to this: https://github.com/clarkie/dynogels/issues/118. You might want to ask on that thread how best to achieve this in the short term, until they implement the feature.

Comment: Thans, will have a look.